# How does the Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteDocuments web part work?

Tags: 2010, web-part, development, tasks

Here is a link to the SiteDocuments web part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544079%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Here is a picture of it on MySites: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVQqM.png

I want to create a web part that is similar to this, but shows tasks instead of documents. My current idea is to crawl the whole web application and look at all lists to determine whether a list has the 'task' content type and has items assigned to the current user. There must be a better way to do this. Any ideas? I want to model my web part on the SiteDocuments web part.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at using the Search API to get a result set of tasks assigned to the current user, and slap on some XSLT to format it how you want, or just plain create a table from the result set.

You want to be looking for stuff like the FullTextSqlQuery class:

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx